# CI CD Pipeline for Angular4 Application in VSTS with Multiple Environment Azure

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Angular 4 front end application which doesn't have any backend like java or .Net. Just a frontend UI which I need to host in Azure as Web App. It have few sets of environment specific variables. Right now I have Separate Builds and Release for each environment specific. This is a kind of tedious work when I need to build and deploy each and every time.

Questions are:

1. I would like to know how to read App Settings that are in Azure App service in Angular 4.
2. How can be have a single build and just change the app settings for each environment specific.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use the environment.json files (and in the build: `npm run build-test`)?

Comment: Hi, Yes we use the file . right now we use the file and do npm run build -test with environment specific. This we use in each build definitions. That is the reason we have multiple CI CD pipeline for each environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 3 environments, but we run only `ng build`, so how we handle the release environments?

When you run `ng build --test/prod/etc.` the file `main.bundle.js` get different values on specific places according to the environment configurations file, so we have only **one** build definition and we run only `ng build`, but in our release pipeline we replace the values on `the main.bunble.js` file according to the correct environment.

You can replace the values with Powershell script or with [Replace task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=replace&target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

Comment: This looks great. Will try it out and update on the answer